Movie where woman injects sedative into wine bottle and remelts wax seal
I think the context for this scene was a guy meeting a girl at a fancy hotel room for a meeting.  He wasn't sure he could trust this woman but ultimately decided to. They talked and drank wine and then as he started to get drowsy it's revealed through a quick flashback she injected a sedative into the wine bottle and then held a match over the wax seal to cover it back up. 

Welcome to Movie.SE. Please be more specific about the movie, try to recall its language, year around which it came out, and a bit more about the actors involved in that scene.

This is from Sherlock Holmes (2009)
This is the scene you're talking about:



